# Python Regex Pattern Replacement

Tags: python, regex, replace

i'm trying to esssentially get any dynamic input from a python script, in this case its a simple file organizing script. I need to make sure that any instance of `[` or `]` is wrapped like this `[[] []]`.

So naturally i tried replace but that just put brackets around all of the escape brackets(the escape brackets for using `glob.glob`)

That proved useless so now i turn to `re.sub` but i can't seem to find a pattern that will only replace `[` or `]` with its escape counterpart if the `[` or `]` has no brackets around it.

I have no idea if that makes sense to anyone but thats pretty much it, here is the messed up re pattern i've got so far, it doesn't like me.

```
pattern = r'[^\[]([\[])[^\]]'
```

Comment: One problem, how would you if a `[` or `]` is used for quoting or they should be quoted ?

Comment: This is for filenames so basically i just have to escape any square brackets for the purposes of using glob.glob, btw the code worked except i changed [$1] to [\1] after that it was perfect, thanks very much.

Comment: Not a solution, but [Pyregex](http://www.pyregex.com/) can help you in testing patterns out quickly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd choose a solution using the higher-order feature of `re.sub` to handle tokens (tokenizing is common practice in parsing computer languages):

```
def replaceToken(match):
    token = match.group()
    if len(token) == 3:
        return token
    else:
        return '[' + token + ']'

re.sub(r'(\[\[\])|(\[\]\])|\[|\]', replaceToken, 'foo[[bar]bloh')
```

Or in one call, if you prefer that:

```
re.sub(r'(\[\[\])|(\[\]\])|\[|\]',
       lambda x: x.group() if len(x.group()) == 3
                           else '[' + x.group() + ']', 'foo[[]bar]bloh')
```

Results:

```
'foo[[bar]bloh' → 'foo[[][[]bar[]]bloh'
'foo[[]bar]bloh' → 'foo[[]bar[]]bloh'
```

Comment: OK great, the problem is that I don't work with Python so I will ask you for a simple thing and if it worked I will give you my up vote. Could you test this string for me: `hello[ from ab ] and this is working []]
working so far [[] and what about [[[ or ]][[` ?

Comment: Returns `hello[[] from ab []] and this is working []] working so far [[] and what about [[][[][[] or []][]][[][[]` for me.  This is what OP wants; I'm skeptic that what he wants makes sense.  I guess a better solution would be to find out if the input already is "quoted" using brackets or not and depending on that a quoting should take place, but that's a little out of scope here.